# Use ast.literal_eval on all columns of a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, lambda, eval

I have a data frame that looks like the following:

```
Category            Class
==========================
['org1', 'org2']    A
['org2', 'org3']    B
org1                C
['org3', 'org4']    A
org2                A
['org2', 'org4']    B
...
```

When I read in this data using Pandas, the lists are read in as strings (e.g., `dat['Category][0][0]` returns `[` rather than returning `org1`). I have several columns like this. I want every categorical column that already contains at least one list to have all records be a list. For example, the above data frame should look like the following:

```
Category            Class
==========================
['org1', 'org2']    A
['org2', 'org3']    B
['org1']            C
['org3', 'org4']    A
['org2']            A
['org2', 'org4']    B
...
```

Notice how the singular values in the `Category` column are now contained in lists. When I reference `dat['Category][0][0]`, I'd like `org1` to be returned.

What is the best way to accomplish this? I was thinking of using `ast.literal_eval` with an apply and lambda function, but I'd like to try and use best-practices if possible. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is a good approach. But I'd suggest using `json.loads` instead.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych - those single quotes mean its not json.

Comment: Please provide an initialized dataframe for test. Are those strings `"['org1', 'org2']"` and `"org1"`?

Comment: What seems odd from a best practices standpoint is to have a column that could be a string or could be a list. If you want to perform other operations on this column, you'll have to keep checking which is which. But maybe its reasonable - it all depends on what happens to the data later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a boolean mask of the values that need to changed. If there are no lists, no change is needed. If there are lists, you can apply literal_eval or a list creation lambda to subsets of the data.

```
import ast
import pandas as pd

def normalize_category(df):
    is_list = df['Category'].str.startswith('[')
    if is_list.any():
        df.loc[is_list,'Category'] = df.loc[is_list, 'Category'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
        df.loc[~is_list,'Category'] = df.loc[~is_list]['Category'].apply(lambda val: [val])

df = pd.DataFrame({"Category":["['org1', 'org2']", "org1"], "Class":["A", "B"]})
normalize_category(df)
print(df)

df = pd.DataFrame({"Category":["org2", "org1"], "Class":["A", "B"]})
normalize_category(df)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
df['Category'] = df['Category'].apply(lambda x: literal_eval(x) if x.startswith('[') else [x])
```